# lldb : Unable to resolve breakpoint in Hello World example

Tags: c++, macos, lldb

I created a Hello World example in C++ and tried to debug it with lldb from the terminal on Mac OSX.

```
> lldb a.out
Current executable set to 'a.out' (x86_64).
```

I can set breakpoints on names (eg. 'main'), but not on line numbers. If I try

```
breakpoint set --file test.c --line 5
```

or

```
b test.c:5
```

I get

```
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending). 
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

The file 'test.c' is located in the current folder. What goes wrong?

Comment: How do you build `a.out`?

Comment: Of course.. forgot the -g flag. Thx!

Comment: Exactly that was my suspicion :). You don't believe how often this happened to me before :)

Answer (score 3):

Acording to [Dwarf Debugging Information Format](http://www.dwarfstd.org/doc/Dwarf3.doc), the line number, file location information are stored in the Dwarf format. Such information is what GDB used to set line number as a breakpoint.

Usually, the Dwarf format information is generated by compiler, such as GCC with the `-g` options. Please try with `-g` options to see whether it works.

Meanwhile, there also [some other debug helpful options in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) which might be more helpful to you, such as `-g3`, compiler will generate more detail information for debug, such as macros.